# The request to db doesn’t work in sqlite3

Tags: python, database

I have a database in sqlite3, I made a new class that opens and closes my db, but requests to db send me errors

```
import sqlite3

class DBConnection:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        return self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.cursor:
            self.cursor.close()
        if self.conn:
            if exc_type is None:
                self.conn.commit()  # this is to commit if no exception
            self.conn.close()
        return False  

def db_connection(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with DBConnection() as cursor:
            return func(cursor, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper  

class Database:
    @db_connection
    def some_query(self, cursor, *args):
 
        cursor.execute(my query)
```

error:

```
cursor.execute(my query)
AttributeError: “Database” object has no attribute “execute”
```

Comment: please, post [mre]. and the full traceback. Right now you show 2 class definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the second argument of the function, but you gave the cursor to the first argument, so your code should look like this.

```html
import sqlite3

class DBConnection:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        return self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.cursor:
            self.cursor.close()
        if self.conn:
            if exc_type is None:
                self.conn.commit()  # this is to commit if no exception
            self.conn.close()
        return False  

def db_connection(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with DBConnection() as cursor:
            return func(cursor, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper  

class Database:
    @db_connection
    def some_query(self, cursor, *args):
        res = self.execute(Your_Query)
```